# Como criar uma váriavel de ligação no Oracle com php

Tags: php, oracle

Preciso criar uma variável de ligação pra usar em tempo de execução com PHP no Oracle, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia definir melhor `uma variavel de ligação no Oracle`? Não conheço Oracle, mas isso me parece ser algum termo relacionado ao banco de dados.

Comment: Quero saber como fazer um código pl sql dentro do código php para definir uma váriavel de ligação.

Comment: Você pode escrever o seu código SQL normalmente e chamá-lo através das funções do Oracle. A função padrão de executar SQL é a [oci_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php)